# Good pdf editor for Mac?

Tags: macos, mac, software-rec, pdf, editing

I'm looking for a free way to edit my PDF files on my Mac.

EDIT: I should precise (thank to "Doug Harris") that I need to edit old PDF files without having the original texts. These are some of my work for a few years, and I don't wannna have to retype everything...

Comment: you have asked for free program and you liked non-free program ;)

Comment: I know, I'd love one that does the same as PDFpen for free, but I guess it would be a dream, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some good but non-free programs:

**[Pagehand](http://pagehand.com/)** is a Mac OS X Program which allows you to save your documents as PDF and later edit them again. It can not open all PDFs though, if they were created with different programs.

[image]

**[PDFpen](http://www.smileonmymac.com/PDFpen/)** looks promising (from SmileOnMyMac, creators of TextExpander), although it's relatively expensive.

[image]

Comment: PDFPen is great!

Comment: Actually PDFpen is the kind I need. Not free, but really great from what I can see.

Comment: but pdfpen is not free

Comment: Why not pay for good software? Programmers gotta put food on the table...

Comment: `Pagehand` link is dead

Answer (score 8):

**[Skim](http://skim-app.sourceforge.net/)** is a free PDF reader and note-taker for OS X. It is designed to help you read and annotate scientific papers in PDF, but is also great for viewing any PDF file.

[image]

Comment: I already use that one, really good in my opinion, but not "editing" enough... Deserves a positive point anyway, for the quality, and actually my question wasn't complete enought...

Answer (score 4):

You don't say what sort of editing you need to do. The standard Mac Preview app has tools for annotating PDFs -- drawing circle, boxes, arrows, highlighting text.

Comment: ...and reordering pages, assembling multiple PDF, extracting some pages...

Comment: Hey you're right. I should precise that my goal is to restructure some old PDF files build on my PC a few years ago. I don't want to redo the whole thing. So I guess PDFpen is the good option for me. But thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a free online PDF editor (Safari & Firefox compatible):

http://www.pdfescape.com

Also:

http://www.smileonmymac.com/PDFpen/

(Or)

http://www.pdfonline.com/pdf2word/index.asp